# Collabnet subversion : module authnz_ldap_module is built-in and can't be loaded

Tags: apache, svn, ldap, collabnet, ldap-client

I am trying to set up a SVN environment. I have installed collabnet svn 1.7.5 version.

If I put the below in httpd.conf by downloading those .so files

```
LoadModule ldap_module opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
```

The server restarts and when I create a repo it says

```
svnrepo -r sample -d "testing" -m -l ldap -g -e
INFO: CollabNet Subversion 1.7.5-1


INFO: Creating repository 'sample' in '/opt/CollabNetSVN/repositories'....
svnadmin: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svnadmin: warning: environment variable LC_CTYPE is en_US.ISO8859-1
svnadmin: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
INFO: Configuring repository 'sample'....
INFO: Creating default directory structure....
svnadmin: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svnadmin: warning: environment variable LC_CTYPE is en_US.ISO8859-1
svnadmin: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
INFO: Verifying repository 'sample' in '/opt/CollabNetSVN/repositories'....
svnadmin: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svnadmin: warning: environment variable LC_CTYPE is en_US.ISO8859-1
svnadmin: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
INFO: Creating authorization file....
INFO: Configuring apache server...
INFO: Checking apache server configuration....
httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/conf/httpd.conf: module authnz_ldap_module is built-in and can't be loaded
```

1. If I put this in httpd.conf

   ```
   LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
   LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
   ```

   httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/conf/httpd.conf: modules cannot be found.
2. if I do not load these modules in httpd.conf the server does not start with the ldap alias

I am not sure where it is failing. Help is very much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN cannot set LC\_CTYPE locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300633/svn-cannot-set-lc-ctype-locale)

Comment: Looks like this one should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11326341/761095

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SVN Edge:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/svnedge/

It gives you everything you need include a web UI for configuring and managing the server making this stuff much easier.  For LDAP, you can just fill out your configuration in a web form and it manages adding all of the right directives.

In this case, I believe at least some of these modules are compiled statically into httpd so you do not need a LoadModule statement as there is no .so file provided.  I believe you can run this to see which modules are compiled in:

$ /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/httpd -l

That said, I would recommend using SVN Edge which makes this all easier to manage plus it includes built in updates via web UI so you can stay up to date easily.